# How to integrate this difficult function?

Tags: calculus

Can you guys help me with the following integral:
$$
\int{\frac{m}{l}} \ dl \cdot \int\left(\frac{v}{l}\right)^2 \ dl
$$
What is standing between the second integral is squared, not the integral itself.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: $\int m/l\ dl = m\ln(l)$ and $\int (v /l)^2 dl = -v^2 /l$ but your notation is not clear.

Comment: This is ambiguous... especially with indefinite integrals - is the $l$ inside the rightmost integral the same variable that enters the left integral? And moreover, does each integral has its own integration constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int{\frac{m}{l}} \ dl \cdot  \int\left(\frac{v}{l}\right)^2 \ dl$

= $m \int{\frac{1}{l}} \ dl \cdot  v^2  \int l^{-2} \ dl$

= $ [m \log l + c_{1}] \cdot [ v^2  \frac{l^{-1}}{-1} + c_{2}]$

= $ [m \log l + c_{1}] \cdot [v^2 \frac{-1}{l} + c_{2}]$

= $ [m \log l + c_{1}] \cdot [\frac{-v^2}{l} + c_{2}]$

Comment: Thanks man! I completely understand your solution, thanks for teh help!

Comment: Shouldn't there be 2 independent integration constants?

Comment: @orion I didn't get your point.

Comment: $(m \log l + C_1)(-v^2 l^{-1}+C_2)$

Comment: Oh ok sorry I forget to write. Actually I use my mobile to answer so lots of problems in typing. And sometime I skip few points. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam Liemburg my previous answer has some problems. Thanks to orion he told me. Now you can see.